# Using Reactive extension (Rx) for MSMQ message receive using async pattern (queue.BeginReceive,queue.EndReceive)

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have been using Rx for a while now for Events on my projects and dedicatedly for Socket programming and the good part is its doing well. Managing my code, performance advantage and much better to execute and interpret.

Lately I have to modify my project's process flow where i need to dump all the incoming data (from socket operations) into queues (**using MSMQ implementation as decided for queueing**).

As MSMQ provides async call for dequeing messages from the queue (but in an wierd pattern).
I have been struggling to use Rx for this purpose now, but enable to do so.

Question : Can some one give me a clean code example to implement Rx for message receiving from queue using Async pattern.

I need the async operator implementation for MSMQ analogous to something like this

```
var data = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<byte[]>(
                        this.receiverSocket.BeginReceive,
                        this.receiverSocket.EndReceive(some parameters);
```

Thanks in advance. ****cheers**** to Rx and .NET

Comment: Can you point me to the class that has the `EndReceive` with parameters? I can't find it...

Comment: i am not sure what you are asking but i am answering of what i understood. I need an Rx implementation (FromAsyncPattern) for BeginReceive & EndReceive that returns me "System.Messaging.Message" object. The async methods are for System.Messaging.MessageQueue object methods. Hope you are now getting better idea now. I am happy and was sure that you will reply superfast when it comes to Rx questions :D

Comment: None of the `EndReceive` methods in the `MessageQueue` class have any parameters other than `IAsyncResult`. What type is your `receiverSocket`?

Comment: oh don't consider that "receiverSocket" object in context of MSMQ. That was just and analogous example what i want to do with MSMQ BeginReceive - EndReceive. Btw "receiverSocket" is of Socket type. The implementation hurdle you said i was also facing the same. Banging my head for nearly 5 hours on a single line of code. I Thought to ask the community. Hope somebody finds a workaround so that i can tool in Rx for MSMQ and use its advantages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be as simple as:

```
var queue = new System.Messaging.MessageQueue("test");
var fun = Observable.FromAsyncPattern((cb, obj) => queue.BeginReceive(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),obj,cb), a => queue.EndReceive(a));
var obs = fun();
```

Comment: I think you're right. The whole "parameters on EndReceive" totally threw me!

Comment: yes. This code works perfectly. But the issue is with the timeout. When the time : case in here is 10 minutes is over and there is no message in the queue then it throws an MessageQueueException. Second problem is that var obs = fun(); subscribe will call the function only once how can i make it recursive in synchronization with the endreceive of the previous request.

Comment: Note to Googlers - though a fine answer at the time, `FromAsyncPattern` is now **obsolete**.

Comment: @Micky so what's the similar solution now?