# Is Reactive Extensions a good fit for a bus?

Tags: system.reactive, cqrs, event-sourcing

I have been using Rx for a little bit now to create an event bus (think CQRS/ES) within a single application, and it seems to work great. However, after surveying a bunch of different Event Sourcing frameworks, I have not seen Rx used once. It seems like a really good fit as opposed to a reflection/container based dispatcher, but perhaps there is something I am missing. I'd rather not spend a bunch of time on something that has a showstopper 3 months in. Is there a reason why Rx isn't a good fit?

Thanks,
Erick

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rx is very definitely a fantastic framework for event-driven and reactive *programming* in general. In fact, I would say that limiting yourself to `IObservable` interfaces for dispatching is actually better form than anything more heavy weight. You are then naturally using a 'messaging' oriented style, which lends itself well to scale and immutability. Separation of concerns becomes natural.

The area in which you may struggle in future is if your systems extends beyond a single application. Rx is very simple within a single application, but requires some effort as soon as you need to add 'infrastructure' between your applications. Not that it doesn't work! It does, as you plumb in different sources for your `Subject` and `IObservable` instances - it just needs to be done manually in some cases, whereas other 'event sourcing' frameworks (what did you have in mind?) may have a bigger range of external 'adapters'.

About Rx being used in this way in general (ie, on the internet). First, remember that there are many other platforms than just .NET and Rx will not show up in any of them. The reactive style might, under a different name.

Secondly, [you](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/rx/thread/a706c9f9-d55c-4781-9a9c-a1b2cdb98924) - [are](http://abdullin.com/journal/2010/9/19/domain-driven-design-event-sourcing-rx-and-marble-diagrams.html) - [not](http://abdullin.com/journal/2010/8/21/rx-works-nicely-with-ddd-and-event-sourcing.html) - [alone](http://blog.perbrage.com/tag/event-sourcing/). Including someone [who likes Rx so much for CQRS they want to do it in Scala and the JVM](http://erikrozendaal.blogspot.com.au/2010/10/event-sourcing-and-state-derivation.html)!

Comment: Thanks for the great response! If you have any pointers on using Rx cross system, that would be great. Right now, I was planning to drop out of Rx into queuing system and back into Rx at the other end.

Comment: It really depends on the queueing system itself as to **how** to do it. But it should be no issue whatsoever. Really no different to anything Rx is ever used for (that is, there's always something 'real world' on one end). One example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005892/using-reactive-extension-rx-for-msmq-message-receive-using-async-pattern-queu

Comment: It's worth noting that Rx has been ported to JS since shortly after its release and I've recently seen a port to Java pop up too. You're not completely tied to .Net when you use Rx.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example of [a message bus in Rx](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/develop/src/ReactiveUI/MessageBus.cs)

Comment: This link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use RX between two processes, then check out:

- [NetMQ.ReactiveExtensions](https://github.com/NetMQ/NetMQ.ReactiveExtensions). This is an RX wrapper that uses ZeroMQ to transport messages over the network.
- [Obvs](https://github.com/inter8ection/Obvs).
- Any RX wrapper over Kafka.
- Any RX wrapper over any inter-process messaging system, such as RabbitMQ.

All these libraries are doing the same thing: they implement IObservable and IObserver interfaces from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an In-Memory Bus that supports Rx in .NET, than you should check out [MemBus](https://github.com/flq/MemBus).

An alternative is to use `MessageBus` from [ReactiveUI](http://reactiveui.net/). But because it does not ship in a dedicated library, so you would have to install the whole ReactiveUI library, which only makes sense in an WPF application and not in legacy WinForms projects.